# Is it possible to change the resolution of specific image with Jython?

Tags: image, jython

this is my first question of stackoverflow and I'm really happy to share information with you guys.

I'm making some Jython scripts that change resolution of specific image, to compare two different images. One of them  is reference image, the other is random image that I want to change resolution. I have tried a lot with many tools like Fiji, but I couldn't be satisfied at all.

Is there any library that is able to resize or change image resolution? Or how can I import libraries of Fiji to my scripts and project?

Please help me.. I haven't solved this for about a month. Thank you guys.

Comment: Might be what you are looking for: http://code.google.com/p/py4ij/